# Unable to load a COM visible dll within a PHP based webpage as a COM object

Tags: c#, php, com

Here's what I've done so far:
I wrote a little C# class library to run GET requests to a REST API.
I compiled it, made sure that it worked within another c# application before trying to import this thing into my webpage. Pulled what I wanted to, worked like a charm whilst operating within another c# console app.

I followed this guide to make sure my dll was COM interoperable and reachable:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/03/10/14009.aspx

Now, I was given this PHP webpage by someone else, and while I am not an expert in PHP, from what I've gathered it doesn't take much to be.

The only real important stuff is here:

```
function APIGet($url) {

$object = new COM("API_Call.ApiCaller");

$result = $object->cURLGET($token, $url);
return $result;
}
```

I wrote that into my function file, which has many other functions that work just fine on the page. The dll contains the namespace API_Call and a public static class, ApiCaller, as well as some other classes that aren't used here.

So then I go to call it on the actual page itself here:

```
$output = APIGet($apicall);
echo $output;
```

From which I get this error (edited for readability):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `API_Call.ApiCall': 

Invalid syntax in C:\xampp\htdocs\canvasAPI.php:32 

Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\canvasAPI.php(32): 

com->com('API_Call.ApiCal...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\CAForm.php(169): 

APIGet('api/v1/courses') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\canvasAPI.php on line 32
```

I have my file, canvasAPI.php with all my functions in it and then the CAForm.php file is the form itself. I've searched high and low for an answer here, but everything either says make the class library COM visible and interoperable, or to enable [COM] com.allow_dcom in php.ini, both of which I already did.

Comment: Did you register your COM library (via regsvr32) or is it in the right folder for XAMPP/PHP to load it?

Comment: Is there any **really** good reason to mess up a `C#`, `COM` and `php`? Why don't you just use a `php` or `C#`?

Comment: I put it within the htdocs folder, then I copied and placed within the php folder as well. Is there a different folder to place it in?

Comment: You have to register your c# DLL with regasm.exe is not important the path where you Save your dll. Is a .net COM library don't use regsvr32 but regasm and you have to bè sure ti launch It with administrator priviliges

Answer (score 0):

For anyone googling this, I just ended up using C# the whole way. I didn't see a point in continuing down the path of messing with custom COM objects in PHP.